# The linkage of symmetric matrix and its eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products

I want to know if the following claim is correct ( I believe that no):

Let A be a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix , $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.
The eigenvalues of $A$  are real but does it mean that:

$$
(A x, x) \geqslant \lambda_{\min }\|x\|^{2}
$$

$$
\lambda_{\min }=\min _{1 \leqslant i \leqslant n }\left\{\lambda_{i} ; A x_{0}=\lambda_{i} x_{i}\right\}
$$

If $A$ is invertible does it change anything?

Comment: A symmetric real matrix has real eigenvalues, but they can be negative. Taking that into account in defining $\lambda_{\min}$, what you say is true.  You should provide more context for this Question  E.g. why do you want to show this, or what did you try?

Answer (score 1):

An important definition is the Rayleigh Quotient of $A$:

$$R:=(Ax,x)/\|x\|^2$$

If you consider its min/max then it’s equivalent to the min/max of

$$(Ay,y)$$

over unit vectors $y$. Now expand $y$ in terms of $A$‘s eigenvectors to prove that for symmetric $A$, the Rayleigh quotient is always between the largest and smallest eigenvalues.

Comment: There is an important ingredient in the proof of what you claim that is worth at least a mention, that the eigenvectors can be chosen to form an orthonormal basis.